# Is the sun brighter at higher altitudes?

Tags: mountains

I was wondering since UV index is higher as elevation increases, is the brightness of the sun changing as elevation increases?

Comment: No, the brightness of the sun is constant.  What changes is that the sunlight has passed through less atmosphere, so less was absorbed/blocked.